# Lightweight way to encrypt/decrypt cookies in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encryption, cookies

We need to keep some flags in the cookies for a spring MVC application
It will be checked and set in an interceptor for every request. Since we need to make the application stateless we don't want to store anything in the session.

My question is how do we encrypt/decrypt the cookie most efficiently? (As less CPU/time as possible).
Currently with AES encryption it takes around 200ms to encrypt and another similar time to decrypt. This is very high overhead considering we need to do it for every request.

**Updated question with AES code taking long time**

```
public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}   

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Can anyone suggest standard practices for this kind of requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lightweight Cryptography. 64 bit block size and and >=64-bit key sizes. See The Nist [doc](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Presentations/NIST-s-Lightweight-Crypto-Standardization/images-media/Talk-FlexibleSymmetricCrypto-meltem-March2018.pdf) from archive.org?

Comment: @kelalaka, Thanks, but the website seems to be inactive. But I will search more for lightweight cryptography.

Comment: try https://web.archive.org/

Comment: For trivial encryption where speed is more important than security, you can always go with the xor cipher: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Comment: 200ms is way too much time to encrypt / decrypt a cookie. Please show your code, possibly there are easy ways to optimize your code.

Comment: I mean, I get 8 ms per full sized (4KiB) cookie on Java using GCM mode and a random nonce (!). OK, that probably all fits in cache so cache switches will add time. But it is still 25 times (!) faster than your implementation and I'm on a cheap ass (i7 dual core low power) laptop that didn't even think it was prudent to switch on the fan any higher than minimum speed.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, That would be wonderful. I am travelling this week end and do not have access to my work laptop. I will share the code on Monday. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I have updated the code.

Comment: That's very generic code and should not take that long. How have you tested the speed? Which provider has been chosen after `Cipher#init`? You can find out by using `Cipher#getProvider`. Of course, there are many things wrong with the code such as making the key and IV a string, and CBC mode doesn't use authentication. You say that it takes a similar time to decrypt, so in that case it is probably not the random number generator to blame (which, I presume, is what you are using for creating the IV for CBC mode, right?). Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, sorry I could not update the code. However we found that `cipher.init` was taking most of the time. And it was getting initialised every time. So we ended up creating a singleton object of initialised cipher. Now it is taking few milliseconds per request.

Comment: You should consider to put your solution into an answer to this question